# htaccess rewrite rules to different urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK I've got an issue with trying to point and redirect two different types of links. I have:

```
www.example.com/listings.php?packageType=Sample&packageTypeSub=Sample2
```

Changing to this when the link is passed through the address bar:

```
www.example.com/Sample/Sample2
```

But, when I have another page which is

```
www.example.com/location.php?place=sampleplace
```

Clicking on this link takes me to

```
www.example.com/sampleplace
```

Which is fine, but it is using the listings.php page and not location.php.
Here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - listings
# Allow packageType
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageTypeSub=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /listings.php?packageType=$1 [L]

# Allow packageTypeSub
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L]


#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - location
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)place=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /location.php?place=$1 [L]


#####################################################
# All other pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The line with 'upload-images' has been added to ignore this folder as I was having issues with the images displaying correctly.

It's looking like the location is passing through listings and not getting to location. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your pretty URL structure is wrong. `/abcd` is routing to both `/location.php` and `/listings.php`. URL scheme should be: `/location/abcd` and `/listings/abcd`

Comment: Rules will come later but first you need to consider change in your URL scheme as I suggested above. If you agree with that I will post an answer.

Comment: OK. How do I change the URL scheme?

Comment: That is for you to decide since you will need to replace your HTML page etc to start using new links

Comment: OK so I have at the moment: location.php?place=NAME 
I use $_GET to call in the NAME and do something with it. Unless I change it to location/NAME

Comment: Yes that **$_GET to call in the NAME** will remain same. See below answer to understand better

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - location
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)place=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ location/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ location.php?place=$1 [L,QSA]

#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - listings
# Allow packageType
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageTypeSub=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ listings.php?packageType=$1 [L,QSA]

# Allow packageTypeSub
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L,QSA]    

#####################################################
# All other pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey this is great! Thank you! Is there a way though to remove listings/?